# Unexpected Notice in CodeIgniter form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-validation

here is my simplified view

```
<?php
echo form_open('form/submit');

echo form_label('User Name:*', 'u_name');
$data= array('name' => 'u_name','placeholder' => 'Your Name');
echo form_input($data);

echo form_label('User emails:', 'u_email');
$data= array('type' => 'email','name' => 'u_email[0][email]', 'placeholder' => 'Email');
echo form_input($data);

$data= array('type' => 'email','name' => 'u_email[1][email]', 'placeholder' => 'Email');
echo form_input($data);

$data = array('type' => 'submit','value'=> 'Submit','class'=> 'submit');
echo form_submit($data); 

echo form_close();
```

and here is my sample controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('u_name', 'Name', 'trim|required|max_length[20]');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('myview', $data);
}
```

**Deviation from Expected:**

When i submit my form without filling name field and after server side form validation goes false, i was expecting form validation error for name field. But it generates a `Severity: Notice` of `Array to string conversion`

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 972

**My Debugging Finding:**

After trouble shooting i find out that my `input as array` fields are causing this Error Notice. But when i submit by filling out all required fields it works fine and `input as array` fields do not generate any `Notice`.

**form_helper.php**

```
function _parse_form_attributes($attributes, $default)
{
    if (is_array($attributes))
    {
        foreach ($default as $key => $val)
        {
            if (isset($attributes[$key]))
            {
                $default[$key] = $attributes[$key];
                unset($attributes[$key]);
            }
        }

        if (count($attributes) > 0)
        {
            $default = array_merge($default, $attributes);
        }
    }

    $att = '';

    foreach ($default as $key => $val)
    {
        if ($key === 'value')
        {
            $val = html_escape($val);
        }
        elseif ($key === 'name' && ! strlen($default['name']))
        {
            continue;
        }

        $att .= $key.'="'.$val.'" '; //Line Number: 972
    }

    return $att;
}
```

Please take a deep look on it and suggest me some solution for this.

**Edit:**

Take a look on below code from actual scenario where i am working, for better understanding

```
<?php
if(empty($additional_alert[0]))
{
   echo '<td id ="empty">No additional alert data found.</td>';
}
else
{
foreach($additional_alert as $key=>$additional_alert):
 ?><div>
<?php
$data   = array('placeholder'=>'Name', 'name'=>'additional_alert['.$key.'][name]', 'value'=>set_value('additional_alert', $additional_alert['name']), 'class'=>'');
   echo form_input($data);
$data   = array('placeholder'=>'Email', 'name'=>'additional_alert['.$key.'][email]', 'value'=>set_value('additional_alert',$additional_alert['email']), 'class'=>''); 
   echo form_input($data);
   echo '<button type="button" name="remove" id="" class="btn btn-danger btn_removes"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>';
?><br>
</div>
<?php
endforeach; 
}
?>
```

and here is image from front-end
[image: and here is image from front-end]

Comment: Either $key or $val is an array: try this before line 972 `if(is_array($val)) { $val = implode(", ", $val); }`

Comment: @ChrisHemmens $val is array but i am astonished there is no error if i submit form by filling out all required fields, as i mentioned in question.

Comment: and further i cant edit line 972 because this is CI own helper

Answer (score 2):

**Retraction of "first" answer**

My original answer (below) is wrong. It turns out that the syntax I claimed as invalid (e.g. `'name' => 'u_email[0][email]'` ) is, in fact, perfectly OK. Either I'd never seen that syntax before or had forgotten about it. (So, I learned (or re-learned) something today which is one of the reasons I like hanging out at SO.)

**The NEW (correct) answer**

First off, using the original example code does not reproduce the problem. At least I cannot make it do so. The question's **Edit** code and DOM screen-shot give better, truer information by providing a better understanding of exactly what the goal is and where the problem might be.

In the OP you are not using "arrays as field names" - not for `u_name` at any rate. But in the edited question, you are! `additional_alert` is definitely an array.

So it turns out @Alex mostly pinpointed the problem. What wasn't clear is that using arrays as field names applies to **all** the "helper" functions.

The fix is to use the EXACT array name.

The "actual scenario" code uses this syntax which produces the *Array to string conversion* error.

```
$data = array(
    'placeholder' => 'Name',
    'name' => 'additional_alert['.$key.'][name]',
    'value' => set_value('additional_alert', $additional_alert['name']),
    'class' => '');
echo form_input($data);
```

What took some time to realize is that the error happens during `set_value()` because, being a "helper", it requires the EXACT array name. If you use the following code there is no error and life is beautiful.

```
$data = array(
    'placeholder' => 'Name', 
    'name' => 'additional_alert['.$key.'][name]',
    'value' => set_value('additional_alert['.$key.'][name]', $additional_alert['name']),
    'class' => '');
echo form_input($data);
```

Obviously, (it is isn't it?) you have to do the same for the `email`.

```
$data = array('placeholder' => 'Email',
    'name' => "additional_alert[$key][email]",
    'value' => set_value("additional_alert[$key][email]", $additional_alert['email']),
    'class' => '');
echo form_input($data);
```

(Note the use of double quotes for the values of `'name'=>` and `'value'=>`? I like that syntax instead of using the dot (.) to concatenate strings. IMO, it is easier to read. And no, you don't need to put single quotes around `$key`.)

**A Suggestion:**

You use the construct

```
foreach($additional_alert as $key=>$additional_alert):
```

That's certainly works but it confused me momentarily a little further on in the line `set_value('additional_alert', $additional_alert['name'])`.

To avoid such confusion I suggest you use the form

```
foreach($plural_values as $key => $singular_value)
```

In your code then use the plural `$additional_alerts`, i.e.

```
foreach($additional_alerts as $key => $additional_alert):`
```

**-- Original (wrong) Answer --**

I believe the error is in `'name' => 'u_email[0][email]',`
should probably be `'name' => 'u_email[]'`.

And `'name' => 'u_email[1][email]'` should be `'name' => 'u_email[]'`

When your view tries to load the bad syntax makes `form_input('$data')` choke. 
When you reference the field in the controller then you use the indexing, e.g.

```
$emails = $this->input->post('u_email');
$email_1 = $emails[0];
$email_2 = $emails[2];
```

Comment: thanks for your time. but in my scenario i cant change array inputs. please review my updated question.

Comment: See my revised answer. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#using-arrays-as-field-names

Thus:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('u_name[]', 'Name', 'trim|required|max_length[20]');
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But  im not using name field as array input.

Comment: array input is email field and that is not required in my controller as i mentioned in my question

Comment: so please can you take a look again on it for this unexpected notice

Comment: Sorry to say, but `'name' => 'u_email[0][email]'` **is an array input**. It's an invalid one because array inputs are a single dimension arrays.

Comment: I believe that what @DFriend is saying still applies. Your format should be `email[]` for each email input .etc. Any variation of `somestr[index][name]` isn't valid.